# Secure way to save ClientId and ClientSecret to authenticate to Azure using Connect-AzAccount

Tags: azure, powershell, security, authentication, az

I am looking for a secure way to have a script running on a local machine and authenticate using these commands in Azure :

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "my_secret" -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("my_client_id", $Password)
$TenantId = "my_tenant_id"
Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $Credential -Tenant $TenantId
```

The issue is that I do not want to save the secret as plain text in the script.  The only solution I have found was to encrypt SecureString password and save it in a file that can be decrypted using a key.  This way, the secret is never in plain text.

Is there any other "clean" way to do this?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Create a credential object one time and use [Export-Clixml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-7) to store it for the current user/machine.

You can then use [Import-Clixml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml?view=powershell-7) to read them back in to your script.

#### Sample

```bsh
# Set credentials
$Credentials = Get-Credential        # Set your id and secret
$Credentials | Export-Clixml -Path $PSScriptRoot\Access.xml -Confirm:$false


# Read the credentials
$Credentials = Import-Clixml -Path $PSScriptRoot\Access.xml
```